# Having trouble drawing arctan graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The graph my code (below) is trying to reproduce is `\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan{x}` but all it creates is a line that shoots up into the y-axis. What is wrong with my graph and how do I fix it?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=both,
                  xmin = -.5, xmax = 10, ymin = 0, ymax = 2,
                  axis lines=middle,
                  enlargelimits]
        \addplot[black] (11,0) node[above left] {$x$};
        \addplot[black] (0,2.2) node[below right] {$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$};
        \addplot[red,dash pattern=on 8pt off 8pt, domain=-15:15]  {1} node[above left]{$y=1$};
        \addplot[blue,samples=1000,domain=0:15]  {atan(x)*((2))/(pi))};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{The graph of $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan{x}$}
        \label{fig:logistic6}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Have you tried googleing "atan pgfplots"? Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160953 helps.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12951, see my answer: `\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad]`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.